# Convert HTML to PDF using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I'm using MVC4 with Visual Basic to make a web aplication.

In my aplication I am using highcharts and some tables that i would like to export to a PDF to be send by mail.

What's the best way to do it? Server side (Visual Basic) or client side (javascript)? And how could i do it? I have found very poor information about this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[Winnovative Html to Pdf converter](http://www.winnovative-software.com/)** or **[Evo Html to Pdf Converter](http://www.evopdf.com/)**

other good example at **[CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5567/Create-and-manipulate-PDF-documents-100-NET)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an Open Soure .NET library I would try [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/).  I have used it in the past with Visual Basic and had no problems.